# Synchronizing a one-to-many relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, one-to-many, crud

If I have a many-to-many relationship it's super easy to update the relationship with its `sync` method.

But what would I use to synchronize a one-to-many relationship?

- table `posts`: `id, name`
- table `links`: `id, name, post_id`

Here, each `Post` can have multiple `Link`s.

I'd like to synchronize the links associated with a specific post in the database, against an inputted collection of links (for example, from a CRUD form where I can add, remove, and modify links).

Links in the database that aren't present in my input collection should be removed.  Links that exist in the database and in my input should be updated to reflect the input, and links that are only present in my input should be added as new records in the database.

To summarize the desired behavior:

- inputArray = true / db = false     ---CREATE
- inputArray = false / db = true     ---DELETE
- inputArray = true / db = true      ----UPDATE

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no `sync` method for one-to-many relations. It's pretty simple to do it by yourself. At least if you don't have any foreign key referencing `links`. Because then you can simple delete the rows and insert them all again.

```
$links = array(
    new Link(),
    new Link()
);

$post->links()->delete();
$post->links()->saveMany($links);
```

If you really need to update existing one (for whatever reason) you need to do exactly what you described in your question.

Comment: Don't do it this way because in the future you may need to store pivot data... or worse - another coder will store pivot data not knowing that the sync is fake.

Comment: Sorry, had my head somewhere else.  Didn't mean "pivot" data.  Still, the point remains.

Comment: Wouldn't it exhaust much faster the primary key capacity, in case of AUTOINCREMENT?

Comment: Useful if you only have two related models. Unfortunately, in my case I have 3 or more models that depend on the ID of the record - so I can't just delete it and recreate.

Comment: This solution can introduce an issue if it will be added a third model with a new relation depending on the second: deleting and recreating records in db change their primary keys. In this case solution can be using uuid.

Answer (score 38):

The problem with deleting and readding the related entities, is that it will break any foreign key constraints you might have on those child entities.

A better solution is to modify Laravel's `HasMany` relationship to include a `sync` method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Relations;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

/**
 * @link https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.php
 */
class HasManySyncable extends HasMany
{
    public function sync($data, $deleting = true)
    {
        $changes = [
            'created' => [], 'deleted' => [], 'updated' => [],
        ];

        $relatedKeyName = $this->related->getKeyName();

        // First we need to attach any of the associated models that are not currently
        // in the child entity table. We'll spin through the given IDs, checking to see
        // if they exist in the array of current ones, and if not we will insert.
        $current = $this->newQuery()->pluck(
            $relatedKeyName
        )->all();
    
        // Separate the submitted data into "update" and "new"
        $updateRows = [];
        $newRows = [];
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            // We determine "updateable" rows as those whose $relatedKeyName (usually 'id') is set, not empty, and
            // match a related row in the database.
            if (isset($row[$relatedKeyName]) && !empty($row[$relatedKeyName]) && in_array($row[$relatedKeyName], $current)) {
                $id = $row[$relatedKeyName];
                $updateRows[$id] = $row;
            } else {
                $newRows[] = $row;
            }
        }

        // Next, we'll determine the rows in the database that aren't in the "update" list.
        // These rows will be scheduled for deletion.  Again, we determine based on the relatedKeyName (typically 'id').
        $updateIds = array_keys($updateRows);
        $deleteIds = [];
        foreach ($current as $currentId) {
            if (!in_array($currentId, $updateIds)) {
                $deleteIds[] = $currentId;
            }
        }

        // Delete any non-matching rows
        if ($deleting && count($deleteIds) > 0) {
            $this->getRelated()->destroy($deleteIds);    
        }

        $changes['deleted'] = $this->castKeys($deleteIds);

        // Update the updatable rows
        foreach ($updateRows as $id => $row) {
            $this->getRelated()->where($relatedKeyName, $id)
                 ->update($row);
        }
        
        $changes['updated'] = $this->castKeys($updateIds);

        // Insert the new rows
        $newIds = [];
        foreach ($newRows as $row) {
            $newModel = $this->create($row);
            $newIds[] = $newModel->$relatedKeyName;
        }

        $changes['created'] = $this->castKeys($newIds);

        return $changes;
    }


    /**
     * Cast the given keys to integers if they are numeric and string otherwise.
     *
     * @param  array  $keys
     * @return array
     */
    protected function castKeys(array $keys)
    {
        return (array) array_map(function ($v) {
            return $this->castKey($v);
        }, $keys);
    }
    
    /**
     * Cast the given key to an integer if it is numeric.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $key
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function castKey($key)
    {
        return is_numeric($key) ? (int) $key : (string) $key;
    }
}
```

You can override Eloquent's `Model` class to use `HasManySyncable` instead of the standard `HasMany` relationship:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use App\Model\Relations\HasManySyncable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

abstract class MyBaseModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * Overrides the default Eloquent hasMany relationship to return a HasManySyncable.
     *
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * @return \App\Model\Relations\HasManySyncable
     */
    public function hasMany($related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null)
    {
        $instance = $this->newRelatedInstance($related);

        $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();

        $localKey = $localKey ?: $this->getKeyName();

        return new HasManySyncable(
            $instance->newQuery(), $this, $instance->getTable().'.'.$foreignKey, $localKey
        );
    }
```

Supposing that your `Post` model extends `MyBaseModel` and has a `links()` `hasMany` relationship, you can do something like:

```
$post->links()->sync([
    [
        'id' => 21,
        'name' => "LinkedIn profile"
    ],
    [
        'id' => null,
        'label' => "Personal website"
    ]
]);
```

Any records in this multidimensional array that have an `id` that matches the child entity table (`links`) will be updated. Records in the table that are not present in this array will be removed.  Records in the array that are not present in the table (Have a non-matching `id`, or an `id` of null) will be considered "new" records and will be inserted into the database.

Comment: can it affect laravel's default has-many relationships in further operations?

Comment: This looks good! but since it's an old answer, I wonder if it's still viable in newer versions of Laravel.

Tested and worked. I will be implementing this in my project.

Comment: @Ashish No, it won't effect laravel's default has-many relationship operation because you are just _adding_ a new function called sync to laravel's HasMany class, and _not changing_ the default laravel's code/behavior.

Comment: @Pratik149 I know that. As I asked this question 2 years ago. thanks anyways.

Comment: @Ashish Haha cool, tbh I didn't expect you to comment back. I actually dropped that comment for someone who would refer to this answer in future, and have the same doubt as you had, so that at least they won't be left unanswered.

Comment: Great function, still in Laravel 7

Comment: Only problem was that it was deleting ALL child records, instead of only the related child records. So I removed the newQuery function on line with $current = $this... and now it works fine. Not sure what that meant to do.

Comment: I used this solution now in 2020 and works perfectly and also is easily adaptable to HasOne relationships, great thanks to you shared this with us.

Comment: Just a note that RelationShips are macroable so there is an easier way to set the sync function using `HasMany::macro( 'sync', syncfunctiongoeshere);`

Comment: its work and its great

Comment: There is a good package for that: https://github.com/korridor/laravel-has-many-sync

Answer (score 8):

You can use [UPSERT](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts) to insert or update on duplicate key, also using relations.

That means that you can comper your old data with your new data, and use an array with the data to be updated with the data to be inserted in the same query.

Also you can delete other ids that are not needed.

Here an example:

```
    $toSave = [
        [
            'id'=>57,
            'link'=>'...',
            'input'=>'...',
        ],[
            'id'=>58,
            'link'=>'...',
            'input'=>'...',
        ],[
            'id'=>null,
            'link'=>'...',
            'input'=>'...',
        ],
    ];

    // Id of models you wish to keep
    // Keep existing that dont need update
    // And existing that will be updated
    // The query will remove the rest from the related Post
    $toKeep = [56,57,58];


    // We skip id 56 cause its equal to existing
    // We will insert or update the rest

    // Elements in $toSave without Id will be created into the relationship

    $this->$relation()->whereNotIn('id',$toKeep)->delete();

    $this->$relation()->upsert(
        $toSave,            // Data to be created or updated
        ['id'],             // Unique Id Column Key
        ['link','input']    // Columns to be updated in case of duplicate key, insert otherwise
    );
```

That will create the next queries:

```
delete from
  `links`
where
  `links`.`post_id` = 247
  and `links`.`post_id` is not null
  and `id` not in (56, 57, 58)
```

And:

```
insert into
  `links` (`id`, `link`, `input`)
values
  (57, '...', '...'),
  (58, '...', '...'),
  (null, '...', '...')
  on duplicate key update
  `link` = values(`link`),
  `input` = values(`input`)
```

This is how you can update all elements of a relationship in just 2 queries. For example if you have 1,000 Posts, and you want to update all the links of all the posts.

Comment: This fails with an error: 1364 Field 'relation_id' doesn't have a default value.
upsert was never intended to be used via relationships as mentioned in the comment below.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/40057#issuecomment-1007535390.
When using upsert, the relation foreign key is not set automatically, you need to add it to your inserted data.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an updated answer inspired from `@alexw` for laravel 7+ working with composite primary keys as well

In your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`'s `boot` method add this macro

```php
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::macro( 'sync', function ( $data, $deleting = true ) {
    $changes = [
        'created' => [], 'deleted' => [], 'updated' => [],
    ];

    /**
     * Cast the given keys to integers if they are numeric and string otherwise.
     *
     * @param array $keys
     *
     * @return array
     */
    $castKeys = function ( array $keys ) {
        return (array)array_map( function ( $v ) {
            return is_numeric( $v ) ? (int)$v : (string)$v;
        }, $keys );
    };

    $relatedKeyName = $this->related->getKeyName();

    $getCompositeKey = function ( $row ) use ( $relatedKeyName ) {
        $keys = [];
        foreach ( (array)$relatedKeyName as $k ) {
            $keys[] = data_get( $row, $k );
        }
        return join( '|', $keys );
    };

    // First we need to attach any of the associated models that are not currently
    // in the child entity table. We'll spin through the given IDs, checking to see
    // if they exist in the array of current ones, and if not we will insert.
    $current = $this->newQuery()->get( $relatedKeyName )->map( $getCompositeKey )->toArray();

    // Separate the submitted data into "update" and "new"
    $updateRows = [];
    $newRows = [];
    foreach ( $data as $row ) {
        $key = $getCompositeKey( $row );
        // We determine "updateable" rows as those whose $relatedKeyName (usually 'id') is set, not empty, and
        // match a related row in the database.
        if ( ! empty( $key ) && in_array( $key, $current ) ) {
            $updateRows[$key] = $row;
        } else {
            $newRows[] = $row;
        }
    }

    // Next, we'll determine the rows in the database that aren't in the "update" list.
    // These rows will be scheduled for deletion.  Again, we determine based on the relatedKeyName (typically 'id').
    $updateIds = array_keys( $updateRows );

    if ( $deleting ) {
        $deleteIds = [];
        foreach ( $current as $currentId ) {
            if ( ! in_array( $currentId, $updateIds ) ) {
                $deleteIds[$currentId] = array_combine( (array)$relatedKeyName, explode( '|', $currentId ) );
            }
        }
    
        // Delete any non-matching rows
        if ( count( $deleteIds ) > 0 ) {
            /**
             * @var \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $q
             */
            $q = $this->newQuery();
            $q->where(function ($q) use ( $relatedKeyName, $deleteIds) {
                foreach ( $deleteIds as $row ) {
                    $q->where( function ( $q ) use ( $relatedKeyName, $row ) {
                        foreach ( (array)$relatedKeyName as $key ) {
                            $q->where( $key, $row[$key] );
                        }
                    }, null, null, 'or' );
                }
            });
            $q->delete();
    
            $changes['deleted'] = $castKeys( array_keys( $deleteIds ) );
        }
    }

    // Update the updatable rows
    foreach ( $updateRows as $id => $row ) {
        $q = $this->getRelated();
        foreach ( (array)$relatedKeyName as $key ) {
            $q->where( $key, $row[$key] );
        }
        $q->update( $row );
    }

    $changes['updated'] = $castKeys( $updateIds );

    // Insert the new rows
    $newIds = [];
    foreach ( $newRows as $row ) {
        $newModel = $this->create( $row );
        $newIds[] = $getCompositeKey( $newModel );
    }

    $changes['created'] = $castKeys( $newIds );

    return $changes;
} );
```

An example of a composite primaryKey model

```php
class PermissionAdmin extends Model {
    public $guarded = [];

    public $primaryKey = ['user_id', 'permission_id', 'user_type'];

    public $incrementing = false;

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Then you can use the sync method as you would normally use it with a belongsToMany relationship

```php
$user->roles()->sync([
    [
        'role_id' => 1
        'user_id' => 12
        'user_type' => 'admin'
    ],
    [
        'role_id' => 2
        'user_id' => 12
        'user_type' => 'admin'
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I did like this, and it is **optimized for minimal query and minimal updates**:

first, put link ids to sync in an array: `$linkIds` and the post model in its own variable: `$post`

```
Link::where('post_id','=',$post->id)->whereNotIn('id',$linkIds)//only remove unmatching
    ->update(['post_id'=>null]);
if($linkIds){//If links are empty the second query is useless
    Link::whereRaw('(post_id is null OR post_id<>'.$post->id.')')//Don't update already matching, I am using Raw to avoid a nested or, you can use nested OR
        ->whereIn('id',$linkIds)->update(['post_id'=>$post->id]);
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that bulk methods like this won't update timestamps or fire model events.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach by using `updateOrCreate` method.

```
$links = [
    [
        'id'=> 24,
        'name'=> '...',
    ],[
        'id'=> 26,
        'name'=> '...',
    ],[

        'id'=> null,
        'name'=> '...',
    ],
];

$linksIds = Arr::pluck($links, 'id');

// Remove links in the database that aren't present in the links array.
$post->links()->whereNotIn('id',$linksIds)->delete();

foreach ($links as $link) {
   $post->links()->updateOrCreate(
       ['id' => $link['id']],
       $link
   );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another manual sync process :

Add Model

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ["name"];

    function links()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Link");
    }
}

class Link extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ["name", "post_id"];

    function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Post");
    }
}

class PostLink extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ["post_id", "link_id"];

    function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Post");
    }

    function link()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Link");
    }
}
```

Here we go

```
// list ids from request
$linkIds = $request->input("link");
if (!empty($linkIds))
{
    // delete removed id from list in database
    PostLink::where('post_id','=', $post->id)->whereNotIn('post_id', $linkIds)->delete();
    // list remain id in database
    $postLinkIds = $post->links()->pluck('post_id')->toArray();
    // remove ids that already on db
    $linkIds = array_diff($linkIds, $postLinkIds);
    // check if still have id that must be save
    if (!empty($linkIds))
    {
        foreach ($linkIds as $id)
        {
            // save id to post
            $post->links()->create(['post_id' => $id]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My version of @alexw. This version is >php 8.1 laravel 8+ and has the option to sync a collection of models and some sonarlint fixes.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Database\Relations;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

/**
 * @link https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.php
 */
class HasManySyncable extends HasMany
{
    public function sync($data, $deleting = true)
    {
        $changes = [
            'created' => [],
            'deleted' => [],
            'updated' => [],
        ];

        $relatedKeyName = $this->related->getKeyName();

        // First we need to attach any of the associated models that are not currently
        // in the child entity table. We'll spin through the given IDs, checking to see
        // if they exist in the array of current ones, and if not we will insert.
        $current = $this->newQuery()->pluck(
            $relatedKeyName
        )->all();

        // Separate the submitted data into "update" and "new"
        $updateRows = [];
        $newRows = [];


        foreach ($data as $row) {
            // If $row is a model, get the array representation
            if (is_object($row)) {
                $row = $row->toArray();
                // Unset, laravel manages these fields. If you manually update/manipulate these fields, remove it!
                unset($row['created_at']);
                unset($row['updated_at']);
                unset($row['deleted_at']);
            }

            // We determine "updatable" rows as those whose $relatedKeyName (usually 'id') is set, not empty, and
            // match a related row in the database.
            if (!empty($row[$relatedKeyName]) && in_array($row[$relatedKeyName], $current)) {
                $id = $row[$relatedKeyName];
                $updateRows[$id] = $row;
            } else {
                $newRows[] = $row;
            }
        }

        // Next, we'll determine the rows in the database that aren't in the "update" list.
        // These rows will be scheduled for deletion.  Again, we determine based on the relatedKeyName (typically 'id').
        $updateIds = array_keys($updateRows);
        $deleteIds = [];
        foreach ($current as $currentId) {
            if (!in_array($currentId, $updateIds)) {
                $deleteIds[] = $currentId;
            }
        }

        // Delete any non-matching rows
        if ($deleting && !empty($deleteIds)) {
            $this->getRelated()->destroy($deleteIds);
        }

        $changes['deleted'] = $this->castKeys($deleteIds);

        // Update the updatable rows
        foreach ($updateRows as $id => $row) {
            $this->getRelated()
                 ->where($relatedKeyName, $id)
                 ->update($row);
        }

        $changes['updated'] = $this->castKeys($updateIds);

        // Insert the new rows
        $newIds = [];
        foreach ($newRows as $row) {
            $newModel = $this->create($row);
            $newIds[] = $newModel->$relatedKeyName;
        }

        $changes['created'] = $this->castKeys($newIds);

        return $changes;
    }

    /**
     * Cast the given keys to integers if they are numeric and string otherwise.
     *
     * @param array $keys
     * @return array
     */
    protected function castKeys(array $keys): array
    {
        return array_map(function ($v) {
            return $this->castKey($v);
        }, $keys);
    }

    /**
     * Cast the given key to an integer if it is numeric.
     *
     * @param int|string $key
     * @return int|string
     */
    protected function castKey(int|string $key): int|string
    {
        return is_numeric($key) ? (int)$key : (string)$key;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Database\Relations\HasManySyncable;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

abstract class BaseModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * Overrides the default Eloquent hasMany relationship to return a HasManySyncable.
     *
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * @return HasManySyncable
     */
    public function hasMany($related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null)
    {
        $instance = $this->newRelatedInstance($related);

        $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();

        $localKey = $localKey ?: $this->getKeyName();

        return new HasManySyncable(
            $instance->newQuery(), $this, $instance->getTable() . '.' . $foreignKey, $localKey
        );
    }
}
```

Usage:

```php
$car->doors()->sync($ArrayWithCarDoorModels);
```

or

```php
$car->doors()->sync($ArrayWithCardDoorData);
```