# update a one to many relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

Suppose we have an `Attribute` model that can have some `Option`s.

On creating an attribute, we can specify some options for that. in fact there is a one to many relation between them.

`Attribute` model is :

```
class Attribute extends Model
{
    use \Dimsav\Translatable\Translatable;

    protected $primaryKey = 'attribute_id';

    public $translatedAttributes = ['title'];
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'creator', 'type'];

    public function options()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AttributeOption::class, 'attribute_id', 'attribute_id');
    }
}
```

And `Option` model is like this :

```
class AttributeOption extends Model
{
    use \Dimsav\Translatable\Translatable;

    protected $fillable = ['attribute_id'];
    public $translatedAttributes = ['title'];
    public $timestamps = FALSE;

    protected $primaryKey = 'attribute_option_id';

    public function attribute()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Attribute::class, 'attribute_id', 'attribute_id');
    }

}
```

For save an attribute with it's options I wrote this :

```
\DB::transaction(function () use ($attributeGroup, $request) {

        $newAttribute = $attributeGroup->attributes()->create($request->all());

        if ($request->has('type') && $request->get('type') == 'select') {
            if ($request->has('options') and count($request->get('options')) > 0) {
                $options = $request->get('options');

                foreach ($options as $opt) {
                    $newAttribute->options()->create($opt);
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->item($newAttribute, new AttributeTransformer());
    });
```

But now consider when a user want to update an attribute that in this case , may want to delete some options and add new ones.

And in this case I do not know how handle options. beacause I do not know how to recognize options that are removed that I can remove them from DB. and how can I update properties of options that does not touched and just fields like `title` ,`desc` , ... are changed.

Comment: which version of laravel are you using

Comment: laravel version 5.5

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, your issue relies on how to enable/disable options based on your current structure? You might need another value in the table that represents active and inactive in that case, you could also use soft delete but that might just be a bit of an overkill if you are planning on activating and deactivating these options regularly. On the last one, if you are simply changing values in the options, you would need to find a means of determining the option being modified by the user. Be it by passing the id of the option from view to know what option exactly he is modifying, or some other means, at that point, if you can determine the option, you simply:

```
$option->{value-to-be-changed} = {value};
$option->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$newAttribute->options()->sync([array of id's])`, but this works on Many to Many . What `sync` does is that it deletes the relation that is not included in the array of id's.

Reference question that might help you:

[Synchronizing a one-to-many relationship in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204485/synchronizing-a-one-to-many-relationship-in-laravel)